# Actualizar la misma tabla para varias base de datos dentro del mismo servidor en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Quiero poder actualizar la columna de la misma tabla en diferentes BD's a la vez dentro del mismo servidor, pero para iniciar antes de comenzar a llenarlo a travez de una tabla temporal queria probar que saliera con una BD, cabe aclarar que la estructura de la tabla es la misma en todas las BD's y que el script se ejecutaria recorriendo fila por fila la tabla temporal por eso necesitaba hacer la prueba con una por lo menos ya luego remmplazaba las variables declaradas.

Sin embargo me arroja el siguiente error, no he encontrado solucion u otra forma de hacerlo, lo hago para evitar hacerlo manualmente 1x1 en cada BD y se haga en automatico:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
The multi-part identifier "pruebas@gmail.com" could not be bound.
```

Este es el codigo:

```
use master
go

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @NAMEBD NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Aqui_va_el_nombre_de_la_BD';
DECLARE @CORREO NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'pruebas@gmail.com';

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + '
USE ' + QUOTENAME(NAME) + ';
UPDATE dbo.configempresa
SET dbo.configempresa.CorreoOrigen ='+@CORREO+';'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = @NAMEBD;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder setear el campo tienes que doblar las comillas.

Además puedes usar un nombre cualificado de 3 partes.

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @NAMEBD NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'devel_she45400';
DECLARE @CORREO NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'pruebas@gmail.com';

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + '

```
UPDATE configEmp 
SET CorreoOrigen ='''+@CORREO+'''
    FROM '+quotename(@NAMEBD)+'.dbo.configempresa As configEmp;'

FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = @NAMEBD;
PRINT @SQL
--EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Cuando veas la sentencia por la ventana de salida, confirma si es la que esperas. Y luego ya puedes comentar el print, y descomentar el exec.

Comment: Gracias si me funciono